Postgres 16.2 query with on conflict gives an error
I begin a transaction
In the transaction I have an insert query which violates several constraints.
Since I do not want to rollback the transaction so I can continue I end my insert query with:
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
Note: Sice there are several things that could go wrong I did not specify any target
Unfortunately I get the constraint violation error in the console and I have to rollback the transaction.
What am I doing wrong?
I would expect to be able to continue querying in the transaction.
Code:

    BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO suez.gebruikers(cprid, upn, inlognaam, peoplesoft_id, actief
    , locatie, naam, familienaam, voorvoegsels, initialen, voornamen
    , email, opmerking)
    VALUES (74965, null, null, null, true, 'VUMC', 'Test JEF Justine',
    'Test', null, 'JEF', 'Justine', 'j.e.test@amsterdamumc.nl', null)
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
    ```
    ERROR:  new row for relation "gebruikers" violates check constraint "chk_actief_upn"
    DETAIL:  Failing row contains (74965, null, null, j.e.test@amsterdamumc.nl, VUMC, Test JEF Justine, Test, null, JEF, Justine, t, null, 2024-05-07, 2024-05-07, null, null, f).
    
                                 Table "suez.gebruikers"
          Column       |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default
    -------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
     cprid             | integer                     |           | not null |
     inlognaam         | text                        |           |          |
     upn               | text                        |           |          |
     email             | text                        |           |          |
     locatie           | text                        |           | not null |
     naam              | text                        |           | not null |
     familienaam       | text                        |           |          |
     voorvoegsels      | text                        |           |          |
     initialen         | text                        |           |          |
     voornamen         | text                        |           |          |
     actief            | boolean                     |           | not null | false
     opmerking         | text                        |           |          |
     date_created      | date                        |           | not null | now()
     date_changed      | date                        |           | not null | now()
     last_login        | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
     peoplesoft_id     | text                        |           |          |
     preferred_account | boolean                     |           | not null | false
    Indexes:
        "gebruikers_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (cprid)
        "uk_inlognaam" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (inlognaam)
        "un_lokatie_email" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (locatie, email)
        "un_lokatie_peoplesoft_id" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (locatie, peoplesoft_id)
        "un_lokatie_upn" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (locatie, upn)
    Check constraints:
        "chk_actief_upn" CHECK (actief = false OR actief AND upn IS NOT NULL)
    Referenced by:
        TABLE "gebruikers_rollen_link" CONSTRAINT "fk_cprid" FOREIGN KEY (cprid) REFERENCES gebruikers(cprid)
    Triggers:
        trigger_record_changed BEFORE UPDATE ON gebruikers FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION record_changed()



it is better to give an example of the request and the error code and text. DDL code for creating a table and constraints will also be useful.

If insert statement violates foreign key constraint, on conflict clause not works. Perhaps chk_actief_upn is check constraint.

You're violating a check constraint and that's not supported. From the manual: ON CONFLICT can be used to specify an alternative action to raising a unique constraint or exclusion constraint violation error.

actief is true  AND upn IS NULL - this cause error. You cannot circumvent this check by using ON CONFLICT.  We can say that this is an error, not a conflict.

I've no idea how this works, but I tested with a duplicate primary key and I get an error or not depending on whether I am inside a transaction. No transaction, no error thrown.

INSERT ... ON CONFLICT only catches errors caused by a unique violation. Other errors, like the check constraint error you experience, are not affected, as are permission errors or others. You have to deal with them in some other fashion.
If you have a short transaction (as most transactions should be), simply roll back and do something else.
If it is a long transaction (batch job), and rolling back the transaction would be a nuisance, you can use savepoints:
BEGIN;

SAVEPOINT a;

INSERT ...;

/* if there is an error */
ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT a;

/* continue the transaction */

COMMIT;

Warning: use savepoints very sparingly. If you have too many of them in a single transaction, your performance is likely to suffer considerably.
